# Global mouse hook on click events in X11

Tags: c++, hook, x11, hotkeys, xserver

I've read a lot of information about X11 graphic system and found a lot of questions about this issue without answer. So let me ask onу more time.

I need classic implementation of hook mechanism (like SetWindowsHookEx) or any other approach in UNIX-like operation systems with **ONLY ONE CONDITION** : ability to listen events **without blocking original event** (like XGrabButton and XUngrabButton do).

P.S. Ben, this is Danila. I need help! ®

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up by grabbing source code from [Xnee](http://www.gnu.org/software/xnee/) - it allows record all input events, including keyboard and mouse with non-blocking logic. The only restriction is that I have to ask if there any events in loop with 100ms interval, but it's ok for me - there is no processor loading at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible do globally (all events/all windows) unless you read low level communication (using pcap or replacing real xserver with proxy that gives you all the data)

To get notification for particular window you change event mask of that window. Server keeps separate copy of event mask for a window per client, and notifies each client interested in events matching mask. For example, if you add `PointerMotion` bit to root window event mask from your connection you'll get pointer events when mouse moves over root window (given it's visible)